# svm.sparse.SVC taking a lot of time to get trained

Tags: python, svm, scikit-learn

I am trying to train svm.sparse.SVC in scikit-learn. Right now the dimension of the feature vectors is around 0.7 million and the number of feature vectors being used for training is 20k. I am providing input using csr sparse matrices as only around 500 dimensions are non-zero in each feature vector. The code is running since the past 5 hours. Is there any estimate on how much time it will take? Is there any way to do the training faster? Kernel is linear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `sklearn.svm.LinearSVC`. This also has a linear kernel, but the underlying implementation is `liblinear`, which is known to be faster. With that in mind, your data set isn't very small, so even this classifier might take a while.

---

Edit after first comment:
In that I think you have several options, neither of which is perfect:

- The non-solution option: call it a day and hope that training of `svm.sparse.SVC` has finished tomorrow morning. If you can, buy a better computer.
- The cheat option: give up on probabilities. You haven't told us what your problem is, so they may not be essential.
- The back-against-the-wall option: if you absolutely need probabilities and things must run faster, use a different classifier. Options include `sklearn.naive_bayes.*`, `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`. etc. These will be much faster to train, but the price you pay is somewhat reduced accuracy.

Comment: I need probability estimates and LinearSVC doesn't provide that(predict_proba function). Any suggestions now?

Comment: svm.sparse.SVC has a quadratic to cubic complexity hence cannot be used for datasets with more than ~50000k samples. A better computer will not solve the quadratic to cubic complexity.

Comment: Just to make that clear classifier models that are scalable w.r.t. the number of samples are: sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression, sklearn.svm.LinearSVC, sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier (and related) and sklearn.bayes.MultinomialNB.

Comment: @user2115183 With a linear kernel, it's almost never a good idea to use `svm.SVC`. Use logistic regression.